# ¿Cómo insertar una imagen en la columna (jsPDF autoTableHtmlToJson)?

Tags: jspdf-autotable

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]no me muestra la imagen siendo que lo hago mal y la muestra la tabla pdf no

Codigo

```
var res2 = pdf.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById("dataTable1"));
pdf.autoTable(
    [![res2][1]][1].columns, 
    res2.data, 
    {
        margin: {top: 300, left:55, right:100, width: 10000}
    }
)
```

Comment: Dónde está la imagen que quieres insertar? No es evidente :/

Comment: lo que pasa con esta variable llamo los datos tabla pero solo muestra los datos no las imagenes que estan cagadas  var res2 = pdf.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById("dataTable1"));
pdf.autoTable(
    [![res2][1]][1].columns, 
    res2.data, 
    {
        margin: {top: 300, left:55, right:100, width: 10000}
    }
)                   me gustaría saber como agregarla